# Are these two linear systems equivalent to each other

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $m$ by $n$ real matrix, where $m>n$ and $\text{rank}(A)=n$.

Let $\vec x$ be the solution of $A^TA \vec x = A^T \vec b$.

Since $\text{rank}(A^T)=\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^TA)$, $A^TA$ should be an invertible matrix, so $A^TA \vec x = A^T \vec b$ has a unique solution.

Does $\vec x$ satisfy that $A \vec x = \vec b$?

Comment: Since $m \ne n$ the dimensions of $b$ in the two equations $A^TAx=b$ and $Ax=b$ are not the same, so theses $b$s are actually two different vectors.

Comment: @gandalf61 Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. The first system should be $A^T A \vec x = A^T \vec b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.  For instance, consider the example of 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1\\0&0}, \qquad \vec b = \pmatrix{1\\2\\3}.
$$
We find that $\vec x = (1,2)^T$ is the solution to $A^TA \vec x = A^T\vec b$, but $A \vec x \neq \vec b$. However, $\vec x$ is the [least squares solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation) to the equation $A\vec x = \vec b$.